# Internal error: JupiterLAB's scheduler extensions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

JupiterLAB's scheduler extensions returns the following message:
[image: Error returned by Jupiter's scheduler extension]

I was trying to do a simple test using JupiterLAB's scheduler extensions with a notebook with a single cell.
This cell contains simple code:

```
    a=1
    print(a)
```

I don't even understand to which iterable it refers to. I am using JupiterLab with Anaconda navigator on a Windows 10 PC.

Comment: are you sure your are running the right code ? because it not possible to get this kind of error when you only running the code that you are referring to.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I also tried to use Jupiter's scheduler with another notebook, and yet it returns the same error.